# Criação de Componentes Angular

Tags: angular

estou iniciando meus experimentos com o Angular (9) utilizando o VSCode como IDE. Contudo estou com uma dúvida (que pode ser básica), mas não vi em nenhum lugar a explicação para tal...

Ao tentar criar um novo componente ex: "menu" através da do comando: **ng g c menu** percebo que a aplicação só cria o arquivo **menu.component.ts**
Como faço para que ele crie os demais arquivos (css, html, e spec.ts)?... até onde li, o comando citado acima fazia isso por padrão. O que mudou?...

Grato a todos...

Marcelo

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver a questão editando os parâmetros da sessão "schematics" do arquivo angular.json

Apenas **removi** o parâmetro  **"inlineTemplate": true** e o processo de criação passou a funcionar criando para mim apenas os arquivos .ts e .html (como eu queria)

```
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "inlineTemplate": true,
      "inlineStyle": true,
      "skipTests": true
    },
```